# Vowel and consonant counter class returning 0

Tags: java

I seem to be doing something wrong here. To keep this short, I have pasted the class (VowCon) where I believe my error to be and have commented in my code to explain what each method does. I suspect my problem to be something particularly between the array and the incrementor method. When I input a string from the method main, and select the option for the number of vowels in the string, it shows zero vowels and consonants.

```
public class VowCon
{
  private char[] array;
  int vowel = 0;
  int cons = 0;

  //constructor that accepts string and converts it to a char array
  public VowCon(String sentence)
  {
    array = sentence.toCharArray();
  }

  //method that increments the vowel and cons variables
  public void incrementor()
  {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if (isVowel(array[i]))
      vowel++;
    else if (isCons(array[i]))
      cons++;
  }

  //determines if each char in the array is a vowel
   private boolean isVowel(char c)
   {
        return (c == 'a' || c == 'e'
                || c == 'i' || c == 'o'
                || c == 'u');
    }

   //determines if each char in the array is a consonant
    private boolean isCons(char c)
    {
        return (((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c >= 'Z')) && !isVowel(c));
    }

    //returns value of vowel
    public int getVowels()
    {
      return vowel;
    }

    //returns value of cons
    public int getCons()
    {
      return cons;
    }
}
```

main program

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ClassTest
{

   /**
    The printMenu methods displays a menu to the user
     */
    public static void printMenu() {
        System.out.println("Please select an option: ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("a. Count the number of vowels in the string.\n"
                + "b. Count the number of consonants in the string.\n"
                + "c. Count both the vowels and consonants in the string.\n"
                + "d. Enter another string.\n"
                + "e. Exit the program\n");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;      // to hold the user's input
        String option;     // to hold the user's input
        char choice;       // to hold a single character
        // create a Scanner object to read keyboard input.
        //  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner keyboard;
 do {
            keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            // ask user to enter string
            System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
            input = input.toLowerCase();
            System.out.println();
            printMenu();
            option = keyboard.nextLine();
            choice = option.charAt(0);
            VowCon words = new VowCon(input);
            switch (choice) {
                case 'a':
                case 'A':
                    System.out.println("Number of Vowels: " + words.getVowels());
                    break;
                case 'b':
                case 'B':
                    System.out.println("Number of Consonants: " + words.getCons());
                    break;
                case 'c':
                case 'C':
                    System.out.println("Number of Vowels & Consonants: \n " + words.getCons() + " Consonants\n " +
                                      words.getVowels() + " Vowels");
                    break;
                case 'd':
                case 'D':
                    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
                    break;
                case 'e':
                case 'E':
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("You did not enter a valid choice.");
            }
            //
            // keyboard.nextLine();    //consumes the new line character after the choice
            // String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
            // letter = answer.charAt(0);
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess, you don't call the `incrementor()` method before you request the vowel or consonant count.

As an aside --

- your isVowel only works for lower case vowels. You'd best generalize it.
- you really should show us how you test the code to get a better answer.

Comment: I thought about not calling the incrementor method being the problem, thanks for the feedback. Where do I call the incrementor method?

Comment: @codenewb: if you called it in the constructor, it would be guaranteed to be called.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is this :

```
   private boolean isCons(char c)
{
    return (((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c >= 'Z')) && !isVowel(c));
}
```

The condition : c >= 'A' && c >= 'Z' should be c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'

Also change isVowel() function to make it work for Upper case alphabets too.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off stepping through the "sentence" like the following

```
public class CountVowelConsonent {
private static final String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
private static final String consonents = "bcdfghijklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHIJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
private int consonentCount = 0;
private int vowelCount = 0;
private String sentence;

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CountVowelConsonent me = new CountVowelConsonent();
    String trial = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.";
    me.setSentence(trial);
    System.out.println("Vowels = " + me.getVowelCount() + ", Consonents = "
            + me.getConsonentCount());
    System.out.println(" " + trial.length());

}

public CountVowelConsonent() {
}

public void setSentence(String sentence) {

    this.sentence = sentence.trim();

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        String letter = this.sentence.substring(i, i + 1);
        if (vowels.indexOf(letter) > -1) {
            vowelCount++;
        } else if (consonents.indexOf(letter) > -1) {
            consonentCount++;
        }
    }

}

public int getVowelCount() {
    return vowelCount;
}

public int getConsonentCount() {
    return consonentCount;
}

}
```